# How to set a different NODE_ENV for my master and develop Git branches in my Google App Engine app.yaml file?

Tags: node.js, git, google-app-engine

This is what my `app.yaml` file for Google App Engine current looks like:

```
# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
env_variables:
    PORT: 8080
    NODE_ENV: development
# [END app_yaml]
```

I have two Git branches:

- master
- develop

I deploy to the staging project from the `develop` branch and to the production project from the `master` branch. I want to set the `NODE_ENV` variable to `production` only when I deploy from the `master` branch. Is this possible? If not, how do you all manage this?

**Note:** I am new to Google App Engine. I am unsure if this is how you even deploy to staging and production servers in the first place. If you have a better solution, please share.

Answer (score 3):

You could have the content of the `app.yaml` different in the 2 branches. I'd also set the app name in the yaml file to the respective develop/production app instead of specifying it via args at deployment time, to prevent acidental deployment to the wrong app.

The `develop` branch `app.yaml`:

```
application: my_app_dev
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
env_variables:
    PORT: 8080
    NODE_ENV: development
```

The `master` branch `app.yaml`:

```
application: my_app
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
env_variables:
    PORT: 8080
    NODE_ENV: production
```

Comment: Then I would get a Git merge conflict / overwrite whenever I merge code from `develop` to `master` unless app.yaml is Git-ignored! Doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Comment: No, you'd get a conflict only once - at the 1st merge after you introduce this scheme. After you complete that 1st merge you *might* get another conflict **only if you change those particular lines of code again**. Give it a try if you're not convinced - I'm using exactly this scheme for my staging & production apps, it works just fine.